# Promisify event based pattern

Tags: javascript, events, websocket

How can I promisify a websocket event based communication, to work like ajax?

```
constructor(){
  this.ws = new WebSocket(...);
  this.ws.onmessage = (event) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    // send data to doRequest
  };

},

async function doRequest(data){
  this.ws.send(JSON.stringify(data));
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // how to wait and get data?
    resolve(data);
  });
}
```

I was thinking to add my own event emmiter and fire event inside onmessage function, then hook the promise from doRequest to that event, but seems kind of convoluted?

Comment: Whats your usecase for this websocket? What data are you sending / retrieving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Websockets can receive and send data in both directions at any time, whereas Promises only resolve once with one value. Thus Promises might not be the right tool here.

If you however want to write an abstraction around *the response to one request*, then a Promise makes perfectly sense:

Add an event listener that listens for the `message` event, but only listen for it **once** and remove it, send the data and resolve whenever the `message` event has been dispatched.

*Remove `function` as this is a `method` of the class you are creating.*

```
doRequest(data){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.ws.addEventListener('message', event => {
      resolve(event.data);
    }, {once: true});
    this.ws.send(JSON.stringify(data));    
  });
}
```

In your constructor only create the `WebSocket` instance.

```
constructor(){
  this.ws = new WebSocket(...);
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
const socket = new YourWebSocketClass();
socket.doRequest({message: 'hello'}).then(message => {
  const data = JSON.parse(message);
});
```

Comment: **async** is totally wrong. **disclaimer** and **advice** is debateable, depends on the exact usecase.

Comment: Quoted from javascript.info: *"The word “async” before a function means one simple thing: a function always returns a promise. Other values are wrapped in a resolved promise automatically."* [Source](https://javascript.info/async-await#async-functions)

Comment: Sure. Thus theres nothing wrong whith marking it `async`.

Comment: You sir, are correct. I'll remove the *async* part.